# static pages with php in movable type

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, movabletype

Is it possible to have Movable Type spit out static html even though there is php code in the banner_header? I want to build a completely static page (no php addHandler allowed). Currently Movable type will echo out the php code if I view the source. Instead of doing that can Movable Type actually process my php so if I said `<?php echo "hi";?>` it would say hi on the page instead of `<?php echo "hi";?>`

Comment: Tell us about your use case and MT Version, I might find a workaround using MT code.

Comment: @Duopixel - I build header and footer using php functions. I would like to basically have banner-header and banner-footer suck in the html from my php function. Then have mt spit out completely static pages. It would be great if I can return a variable or echo out what I want in the banner-header. MT 4.35

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you build your header and footer with MT instead?

Answer (score 0):

A static Movable Type site produces html that is no different from a hand coded html file. I'm afraid it's impossible if you can't touch the .htaccess file (to add the handler).

Comment: that was what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're publishing your site pages with .html extension, but without specifying the 'addhandler' .htaccess rule to interpret .html pages as PHP, your php coding would appear as such, instead of being interpretted as PHP coding.

This has nothing to do with the movable type capabilities.

You could either implement the addhandler .htaccess rule to make your .html pages be handler as PHP pages, or you could change your site files extensions to .php or finally you could just code your header and footer within movable type using static html coding.